# Save numpy array as TIFF sequence using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff, python-imaging-library

I have seen an example of loading a TIFF sequence of say a 3D tiff stack or animation. However I cannot figure out how to do the opposite, taking say, a 3D+ numpy array and saving it as a TIFF sequence. Are there are any examples of encoding this? I can read a 2D array using PIL.fromarray. It would be nice if this method had some way of loading a multi-dimensional array but a naive method call will throw an unsupported-type exception.

Presumably if one did write such a sequence they might also want to add some headers to dictate channels, time and so forth. My particular bias is being able to open such images in applications like ImageJ/FIJI or converting from TIFF to other formats. Maybe there are better ways to go about this in the first place.

Comment: thanks. yes, i had used tifffile and it does work but still, i was curious about using PIL also. There is nothing wrong with the tifffile.py route- it works nicely and the code is well commented. I came across this when working with CZIFile which (as you know) makes use of tifffile.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for saving a tiff stack in PIL? I would certainly be interested! :)

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm afraid i did not find anything for PIL and I have not looked since. In fact these days, I think I am using skimage.io for reading in TIFF stacks too, so PIL is not something I have been focusing on of late. Can one save TIFF stacks with skimage.io? not sure off the top of my head...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but in case anyone comes here looking for the answer, this does seem to have been solved nicely.

e.g.

```
im.save("filename.tiff", format="TIFF", save_all=True)
```

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/3.4.0.html